# Typecasting int to float turns DivideByZeroException into Infinity

Tags: c#, floating-point-precision, divide-by-zero

I wrote a simple `divide` function in C#:

```
    private string divide(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("Result: {0}", a / b);
    }
```

Calling `MessageBox.Show(divide(3, 0))` results in, as you would expect, a `DivideByZeroException`.

So I decided to typecast `a` into a float (to get a non-whole-number return value), like so:

```
    private string divide(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("Result: {0}", (float)a / b);
    }
```

Oddly enough, this now shows me **Result: Infinity**.

This seems like a bug to me, although I could be mistaken. Is it because the result is now a float, and it's seen as essentially the return value of `3 / 1 x 10^-99999` or something similar?

I'm quite flabbergasted at this result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division by zero: int vs. float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480020/division-by-zero-int-vs-float)

Comment: float never throws an exception when dividing by zero.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262286/why-does-c-sharp-allow-dividing-a-non-zero-number-by-zero-in-floating-point-type

Comment: I'll add that using doubles wouldn't have changed anything! (technically you would have received `Double.PositiveInfinity` instead of `Single.PositiveInfinity`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the behavior when you convert `int` to `float`. This has been taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation:

> Dividing a floating-point value by zero will result in either positive
>   infinity, negative infinity, or Not-a-Number (NaN) according to the
>   rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic. Floating-point operations never throw an
>   exception. For more information, see [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28VS.80%29.aspx) under the *Arithmetic Overflow* section:

> Floating-point arithmetic overflow or division by zero never throws an
>   exception, because floating-point types are based on IEEE 754 and so
>   have provisions for representing infinity and NaN (Not a Number).

Answer (score 1):

No, for float operations that is correct.

> The IEEE floating-point standard, supported by almost all modern floating-point units, specifies that every floating point arithmetic operation, including division by zero, has a well-defined result. The standard supports signed zero, as well as infinity and NaN (not a number). There are two zeroes, +0 (positive zero) and −0 (negative zero) and this removes any ambiguity when dividing. In IEEE 754 arithmetic, a ÷ +0 is positive infinity when a is positive, negative infinity when a is negative, and NaN when a = ±0. The infinity signs change when dividing by −0 instead.
>
> [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)