# Java Exception Handling :/zeo

Tags: java

i am using java jdk1.8 version.
when i devide any number by zero(0)
it shows message "Infinity".While it should shows at runtime ArithmeticException :/zero.What can be the reason.

```
class division
{
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
          float a=10,b=0;
          System.out.println(a/b);
      }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division by zero: int vs. float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480020/division-by-zero-int-vs-float)

Comment: yes,as i see when i declare variable as int then there is ArithmaticException but in the case of float or double it shows "Infinity" .Why?I need more simplified answer.

Comment: [Linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480020/division-by-zero-int-vs-float) has six answers already. What is not clear after reading them?

Answer (score 6):

No it shouldn't issue an exception.

Java insists on the IEEE754 standard for floating point. This states that a division by a floating point zero yields NaN if the *numerator* is also zero, +Infinity if the numerator is positive, and -Infinity if the numerator is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically,

x / 0 can be:

- unkown if x = 0, since 0 / 0 = p can be easily solved to 0 = 0 * p, which is true for any p
- invalid, since x / 0 = p can be easily solved to p * 0 = x, which, since x != 0 is untrue and paradoxical
- infinite, since if we have a number y infinitely close to 0, rounded to 0, then x / 0 ~ x / y = +- infinity, depending on the signs of x and y

As @Bathsheba pointed out in his answer:

> Java insists on the IEEE754 standard for floating point.

So, if we take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), for example, then we can see that:

> Division by zero (an operation on finite operands gives an exact
>   infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0)) (returns ±infinity by default).

Comment: Note though that, mathematically speaking, log(0) is a much more *evil* infinity than x / 0 for non-zero x.

Comment: @Bathsheba, assuming that that 0 is an infinitely small positive real number, then the result will be negative infinity. If it is exactly 0, or negative 0, then it is outside of domain. Off course, I assume that the base of the logarithm is a real number greater than 1. A base between 0 and 1 would invert the picture, not to mention negative bases. So, it is evil, but I wonder which evil attribute of that value are you referring to?

Comment: The *type* or *order* of infinity of log(0) gives mathematicians breakdowns.

Comment: @Bathsheba, that's true. Interesting topic :)